# I want fingerprint to appear only on the white color of the noise texture in the left how can I do that?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, shader-nodes, roughness

[![The right plane have fingerprints roughness i want them to appear

only in the white value in the left plane][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXWxw.jpg)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuyti.jpg]

Comment: What does it give you mix them through a Color > MixRGB in Multiply mode?

Comment: Yes sir it worked thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Mix them through a *Color > MixRGB* node in *Multiply* mode